# App crashing on a mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, crash

I have written an app, that is crashing for ONE user. (out of 50). he gets a message with written "the application quitted unexpectedl" and this is the message:

Updated with full report as requested

```
            Thread 0 Crashed: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
            0 ??? 000000000000000000 0 + 0
            1 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100def22e -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 416
            2 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100def01b -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 259
            3 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100dee406 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 336
            4 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100deca91 loadNib + 226
            5 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100debfa1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 248
            6 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100debdd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
            7 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100de935b NSApplicationMain + 279
            8 mad-sharky.com.Stockuploader 0x0000000100001194 0x100000000 + 4500

            Thread 1: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
            0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100747c0a kevent + 10
            1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100749add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
            2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x00000001007497b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
            3 libSystem.B.dylib 0x00000001007492de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
            4 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100748c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
            5 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100748aa5 start_wqthread + 13

            Thread 2:
            0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100748a2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
            1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100748e3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
            2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0000000100748aa5 start_wqthread + 13

            Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
             rax: 0x0000000108a1b7d0 rbx: 0x0000000108a1b7d0 rcx: 0x000003ffffffffff rdx: 0x00000000ffffffff
             rdi: 0x0000000108a1b7d0 rsi: 0x0000000108a240c0 rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff620 rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff5b8
             r8: 0x0000000100cdb2a0 r9: 0x0000000000000000 r10: 0x0000000107e16480 r11: 0x00007fff5fbff4d0
             r12: 0x0000000000000010 r13: 0x0000000108a1b770 r14: 0x000000010000d6b0 r15: 0x0000000100cdd630
             rip: 0x0000000000000000 rfl: 0x0000000000010202 cr2: 0x0000000000000000

            Binary Images:
             0x100000000 - 0x10000afff +mad-sharky.com.Stockuploader 1.0 (1) <0A7D614F-C5B3-3627-8C1D-0CF16DA91644> /Users/adamdale/Desktop/Stockuploader_4_MAC_V1.0 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Stockuploader
             0x100011000 - 0x100011ff7 com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
             0x100014000 - 0x100192ff7 com.apple.WebKit 6533.21 (6533.21.1) <C89E93DE-3BFD-2E7A-2A49-356885FA1CDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
             0x100267000 - 0x100267ff7 com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <68B0BE46-6E24-C96F-B341-054CF9E8F3B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
             0x10026a000 - 0x1004ecfff com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <E10E4DB4-9D5E-54A8-3FB6-2A82426066E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
             0x100664000 - 0x10071aff7 libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
             0x10072e000 - 0x1008effef libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
             0x100981000 - 0x100abffff com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <9DFE798D-AA52-6A9A-924A-DA73CB94D81A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
             0x100b57000 - 0x100ccefe7 com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <BB4E5158-E47A-39D3-2561-96CB49FA82D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
             0x100de7000 - 0x1017e1ff7 com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
             0x101dd9000 - 0x101dddff7 libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
             0x101de0000 - 0x102114fef com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
             0x10218e000 - 0x102262fe7 com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <C83E2BA1-1818-B3E8-5334-860AD21D1C80> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
             0x1022d6000 - 0x102320ff7 com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <2EF19055-D7AE-4D77-E589-7B71B0BC1E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
             0x10234a000 - 0x102407fff com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359 (359) <DAAB42A1-89A6-9644-CB21-50BA66417F12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
             0x102461000 - 0x1024f1fff com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <3403E658-A54E-A79A-12EB-E090E8743984> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
             0x10252f000 - 0x10256afff com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
             0x102584000 - 0x102624fff com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
             0x10266a000 - 0x102692fff com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
             0x1026ac000 - 0x10270cfe7 com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <4F071EF0-8260-01E9-C641-830E582FA416> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
             0x102730000 - 0x1028eefff libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <4274FC73-A257-3A56-4293-5968F3428854> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
             0x10295d000 - 0x102963ff7 com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
             0x10296c000 - 0x102982fef libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <83676D2E-23CD-45CD-BE5C-35FCFFBBBDBB> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
             0x10298b000 - 0x10299afff com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
             0x1029a3000 - 0x102a20fef libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
             0x102a81000 - 0x102a92ff7 libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <97019C74-161A-3488-41EC-A6CA8738418C> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
             0x102a97000 - 0x102aa5ff7 libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
             0x102aa9000 - 0x102af5fff libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
             0x102b02000 - 0x102d8afef com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <015C9A08-3D07-9462-8E91-DB1924349621> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
             0x102e82000 - 0x102f3bfff libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
             0x102f4b000 - 0x102f8cfff com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <78D48D27-A9C4-62CA-2803-D0BBED82855A> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
             0x102fb0000 - 0x102fdbff7 libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <8AB4CA9E-435A-33DA-7041-904BA7FA11D5> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
             0x102fe6000 - 0x1030fdfef libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <1B27AFDD-DF87-2009-170E-C129E1572E8B> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
             0x103126000 - 0x103126ff7 com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <FA427C37-CF97-6773-775D-4F752ED68581> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
             0x103129000 - 0x103319fef com.apple.JavaScriptCore 6533.20 (6533.20.20) <5626170D-00AE-33B1-03FF-256E9794150D> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
             0x10338e000 - 0x10339dfef com.apple.opengl 1.6.13 (1.6.13) <516098B3-4517-8A55-64BB-195CDAA5334D> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
             0x1033a6000 - 0x103743fe7 com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
             0x103871000 - 0x1044ecfef com.apple.WebCore 6533.21 (6533.21.1) <15CE3700-C6DC-7F94-5394-4CF78040A40D> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
             0x104acb000 - 0x104acbff7 com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
             0x104ace000 - 0x104ad3ff7 com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <4D84803B-BD06-D80E-15AE-EFBE43F93605> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
             0x104adb000 - 0x104adefff com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <BD1B0A22-1CB8-263E-FF85-5BBFDE3660B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
             0x104ae4000 - 0x104de2fff com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
             0x104f0e000 - 0x104f25fff com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <79AB2131-2A6C-F351-38A9-ED58B25534FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
             0x104f3f000 - 0x104ff4fe7 com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <8C36373C-5473-3A6A-4972-BC29D504250F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
             0x105027000 - 0x105042ff7 com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <9D50701D-54AC-405B-CC65-026FCB28258B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
             0x105053000 - 0x105055fff com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <CA8564FB-B366-7413-B12E-9892DA3C6157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
             0x10505a000 - 0x10505dff7 com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <AEF55AF1-54D3-DB8D-27A7-E16192E0045A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
             0x105062000 - 0x10506dff7 com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <3D65E89B-FFC6-4AAF-D5CC-104F967C8131> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
             0x105077000 - 0x105773ff7 com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
             0x105865000 - 0x105a23ff7 com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4 (3.0.4) <6212CA66-7B18-2AED-6AA8-45185F5D9A03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
             0x105a8f000 - 0x105b0dff7 com.apple.CoreText 151.10 (???) <54961997-55D8-DC0F-2634-674E452D5A8E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
             0x105b4b000 - 0x105be5fff com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <FBC907AF-C3EF-CAF1-3705-13DC91B29114> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
             0x105c0e000 - 0x105ccffef com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.6 (4.6.6) <BB2C5813-C61D-3CBA-A8F7-0E59E46EBEE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
             0x105d0c000 - 0x105d5fff7 com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
             0x105d8b000 - 0x105da0ff7 com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <1AE1FE8F-2204-4410-C94E-0E93B003BEDA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
             0x105dae000 - 0x105e33ff7 com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
             0x105e69000 - 0x105eaafef com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
             0x105ec2000 - 0x105ed6ff7 com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <63C87CF7-56B3-4038-8136-8C26E96AD42F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
             0x105ee7000 - 0x105ee7ff7 com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <15DF8B4A-96B2-CB4E-368D-DEC7DF6B62BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
             0x105eea000 - 0x105f39fef libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <5DE9F066-9B64-CBE4-976A-CC7B8DD3C31A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
             0x105f46000 - 0x105f4bfff libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <95443F88-7D4C-1DEE-A323-A70F7A1B4B0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
             0x105f50000 - 0x105f6dff7 libPng.dylib ??? (???) <4815A8F2-24A0-E783-8A5A-7B4959F562D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
             0x105f75000 - 0x105f77fff libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <76C1B129-6F25-E43C-1498-B1B88B37163B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
             0x105f7b000 - 0x105fa2ff7 libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <B9AA5816-8CCB-AFCB-61FD-3820C6E8219D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
             0x105faa000 - 0x106087fff com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
             0x106096000 - 0x106096ff7 com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <4CCE5D69-F1B3-8FD3-1483-E0271DB2CCF3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
             0x106099000 - 0x1060e1ff7 libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <98FC4457-F405-0262-00F7-56119CA107B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
             0x1060e9000 - 0x106153fe7 libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <AF0EA96D-000F-8C12-B952-CB7E00566E08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
             0x10615d000 - 0x106967fe7 libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <EEE5CE62-9155-6559-2AEA-05CED0F5B0F1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
             0x1069b0000 - 0x106df4fef libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <E14EC4C6-B055-A4AC-B971-42AB644E4A7C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
             0x106f81000 - 0x1070a0fe7 libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
             0x107108000 - 0x107109ff7 com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <5952A9FA-BC2B-16EF-91A7-43902A5C07B6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
             0x10710d000 - 0x1071cefff libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <A00BB0A7-E46C-1D07-1391-194745566C7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
             0x1072c5000 - 0x1072fffff libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <7982734A-B66B-44AA-DEEC-364D2C10009B> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
             0x10730e000 - 0x1073befff edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
             0x1073e4000 - 0x107405fff libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F322F47-0584-CB7D-5B73-9EBD670851CD> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
             0x10740f000 - 0x107456ff7 com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <923E33CC-83FC-7D35-5603-FB8F348EE34B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
             0x10747b000 - 0x107560fef com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
             0x1075af000 - 0x1076e4fff com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <E5D7DBDB-6DDF-E6F9-C71C-86F4520EE5A3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
             0x10775e000 - 0x1077b3ff7 com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <8807EB96-D12D-8601-2E74-25784A0DE4FF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
             0x1077d1000 - 0x1077e7fe7 com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
             0x1077f4000 - 0x107819ff7 com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
             0x107832000 - 0x107863fff libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <7F102A07-E4FB-9F52-B2F6-4E2D2383CA13> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
             0x10786a000 - 0x10788dfff com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
             0x107896000 - 0x10789cff7 IOSurface ??? (???) <8E302BB2-0704-C6AB-BD2F-C2A6C6A2E2C3> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
             0x1078a5000 - 0x1078eefef libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <1C050088-4AB2-2BC2-62E6-C969F925A945> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
             0x1078fd000 - 0x107911fff libGL.dylib ??? (???) <2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
             0x107921000 - 0x107a3bfef libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <8A4B86E3-0FA7-8684-2EF2-C5F8079428DB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
             0x107a5c000 - 0x107a5fff7 libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <E03D7C81-A3DA-D44A-A88A-DDBB98AF910B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
             0x107a64000 - 0x107a69fff libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <1D0D3531-9561-632C-D620-1A8652BEF5BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
             0x107a6e000 - 0x107aedfe7 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
             0x107b23000 - 0x107b24ff7 com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <53299948-2554-0F8F-7501-04B34E49F6CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
             0x107b29000 - 0x107b29ff7 com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <96FB6BAD-5568-C4E0-6FA7-02791A58B584> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
             0x107b2c000 - 0x107bb8fef SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <3F1F2727-C508-3630-E2C1-38361841FCE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
             0x107bfc000 - 0x107c03fff com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4FF6AD25-0916-B21C-9E88-2CC42D90EAC7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
             0x107c0c000 - 0x107c12ff7 com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
             0x107c1a000 - 0x107c33fff com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <401557B1-C6D1-7E1A-0D7E-941715C37BFA> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
             0x107c48000 - 0x107c97ff7 com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <0731C40D-71EF-B417-C83B-54C3527A36EA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
             0x107cb8000 - 0x107cd8ff7 com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.12) <A4685F06-5881-35F5-764D-C380304C1CE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
             0x107ce2000 - 0x107cf4fe7 libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
             0x107cfb000 - 0x107cfcfff liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
             0x107de7000 - 0x107df4fe7 libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <1C35FA50-9C70-48DC-9E8D-2054F7A266B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
             0x7fff5fc00000 - 0x7fff5fc3be0f dyld 132.1 (???) <29DECB19-0193-2575-D838-CF743F0400B2> /usr/lib/dyld
             0x7fffffe00000 - 0x7fffffe01fff libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

is this kind of problem usually related to the mac or the application? its strange that it is working on all other macs. the OS version is compatible with my build settings.

---EDIT----

The one user, today became THREE users. problem starts to be big..

---UPDATE----

based on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_900148&feature=iv&src_vid=srbdMHivkpo&v=akjVaF09mSY) they are running a 64 bit system on a 32 bit processor. my program is compiled for a 64 bit system. could this be the cause? if so, how can i convert my app to an app that can be compiled also for a 32 bit system?

Comment: Thinking of all the ways that this user is different than the others- OS version, paths, user name, memory, ... Can you get the stack dump at time of crash? Usually when you see what used a null pointer it's easy to figure out from there. Some function call failed and returned a NULL that you tried using  - what function and why? Not enough data...

Comment: Someone **Voted to Close** as Not a real question. I think this is a real question as I too faced this kind of crashing.

Comment: thanks for replying. i have the full report. updating the first post.

Comment: I think you need to find out what is special about this particular user.  Is he running a different version of OSX?  Is he running on different hardware?

Comment: could this: `Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):` mean that he is on a 32 bit machine and the app is for 64 bit machines?

Comment: What is com.mad-sharkey.stockUploader?  Something is going wrong while unpacking the top-level objects in app's main nib; I'd check the user's sandbox settings too while we're at it.

Comment: stockuploader is my application! its working everywhere else.. except on this pc.. what does it mean that something is going wrong while unpacking?

Comment: At startup, your application reads the main NIB file and creates your window, its window controller, and whatever other objects it contains. The stack dump says you're crashing while instantiating a top-level object, or perhaps an object contained within it.

Comment: thanks. why would that crash on some systems and on Others not?

Comment: According to the report, I would suggest you to check your nib file. For some controls, some setting are not compatible with older OS. For example, UILabel's attributedText is available on iOS 6, and if you choose Text:Attributed in nib, it might crash on iOS 5. Unfortunately, it's impossible to find out the problematic nib by the report, you need take some time to check it.

Comment: wouldn't the compiler give an error message if i try to compile for a older version that is not fully compatible with what i used? for example, OSX10.5 if i compile i get error. but if i compile for OSX10.6 then it works..

Comment: updated the main post. please see at the end the added part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that those users are using a 32 bit processor and a 64 bit application doesnt work. i disabled ARC and set the code to compile for 86_64 and it works now. still lots of error mesage and code to adapt but when all the red ones are gone it compiles and runs. thanks anyway to all who helped, upvoting every post!

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information here to help you very much.

You're crashing, with a null pointer error, while instantiating objects from a the application's nib file. Most likely, your unusual user is (a) missing a library, or (b) is otherwise dereferencing a nil pointer, perhaps in its constructor.

Comment: thanks! what informations would i have to post in order to have enough informations to find out what is causing it? libraries, i am only using standard libraries. no third party ones...

Comment: First, can you reproduce the issue on the offending machine?  If you have access, set breakpoints or use diagnostic NSLog() messages to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Assuming you can't reproduce the problem or can't get at the problematic Mac, I'd look first at your NSDocument's didLoadNib: method, or your view's -initWithFrame: and awakeFromNib methods.

Comment: unfortunately i cant reproduce it and dont have access to one of those macs.. thanks for your hint.. will check Tomorrow those methods (its late here in italy..) and report back! thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should implement `alloc` on all your custom UI classes and log when each of them is created, because you seem to be crashing out on a custom UI instantiation:  `com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100def22e -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 416`